# SHIFT+HOME and SHFT+left/right keys for text fields not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp, keycode

I am using Struts2 `<s:textfield />` tag and the below code calculates and checks / validates the value entered in the text field on the fly with JS.

It also updates the total entered in `textfield` list, these are handled by `onblur` and `onkeydown` events as below.

```xml
<s:textfield id = "fieldid" 
           name = "xyz" 
         onblur = "javascript:calculateTotal()" 
      onkeydown = "javascript:checkDecimal(this); return checkDecimal(event);" 
 />
```

By using this code <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>HOME</kbd> , <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Left</kbd> and <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>Right</kbd> keys functionalities are not working.

Is there any possibilities that this is due to `onblur` and `onkeydown` events ?

```js
function checkDecimal(evt) {
    var charCode;
    var version = msieversion();
    if(version==8){
        charCode = (window.event) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
        charCode = (window.event) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    }else{
        charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : evt.keyCode;
    }
    if (!evt.shiftKey) {
        if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)  || 
            (charCode == 8)                     || 
            (charCode == 46)                    || 
            (charCode == 190)                   || 
            (charCode == 35 )                   || 
            (charCode == 36)                    || 
            (charCode == 9)                     || 
            (charCode == 37)                    || 
            (charCode == 39)                    || 
            (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105) || 
            (charCode == 110)) 
        { 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    } else {
        if (charCode == 9) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code will look like this...

```
 if (!evt.shiftKey) {
        if ((charCode >= 48 && charCode <= 57)  || 
            (charCode == 8)                     || 
            (charCode == 46)                    || 
            (charCode == 190)                   || 
            (charCode == 35 )                   || 
            (charCode == 36)                    || 
            (charCode == 9)                     || 
            (charCode == 37)                    || 
            (charCode == 39)                    || 
            (charCode >= 96 && charCode <= 105) || 
            (charCode == 110)) 
        { 
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }     else if(evt.shiftKey) {

    if ((charCode == 35 ) || (charCode == 39) || (charCode == 37) ||  (charCode == 36)) {
                    return true;
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the `keypress` event instead of the `keydown` one.

The `keypress` will intercept the resultant character, 

while the `keydown` will interpret the <kbd>SHIFT</kbd> as a button itself.

Then try using

```
<s:textfield id = "fieldid" 
           name = "xyz" 
         onblur = "javascript:calculateTotal()" 
     onkeypress = "javascript:checkDecimal(this); return checkDecimal(event);" 
 />
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you need to validate and allow only the decimal values. In that case this snippet will do the job.

```html
<input id = "fieldid" 
       name = "xyz" 
     onblur = "javascript:calculateTotal()"  onkeypress="return checkDecimal(event);" />
<script>
function isNumeric(n) {
  return !isNaN(parseFloat(n)) && isFinite(n);
}
function checkDecimal(evt) {
    var charCode = (window.event) ? evt.keyCode : evt.which;
    var currentVal = String.fromCharCode(charCode);
    var val = document.getElementById(evt.currentTarget.id).value + '' + currentVal;
    return (evt.shiftKey || isNumeric(val) || isNumeric(currentVal) || String.fromCharCode(currentVal) == '.');
}
</script>
```

Please feel free to correct me if I was not read the question correctly.